# Problem with downloading images from Firebase Storage (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

In my app there is a problem with downloading images from Storage. The uploading, authentication, firestore work, so the app is connected successfully to Firebase. The firebase storage gets the request but my completion block doesn't run.

Here is the code:

```
 let storage = Storage.storage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadImage()
}

func downloadImage() {

    let ref = storage.reference().child("cv.jpg")

    ref.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }else {
            if let imageData = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get any error

Comment: Is your path correct? If it does not return any error, it could be just entering the `else` and when unwrapping the data, it just doesn't exists - it's `nil`.

Comment: Oh, is your child name exactly "cv.jpg"?

Comment: Yes and it is located in the root of my storage

Comment: the completion block doesnt run

Comment: Well, I guess there's a timeout that is never "reached".
Try changing values from your `Storage`. Properties suggestions: `maxOperationRetryTime` and `maxDownloadRetryTime`. You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/Storage?hl=pt-br)

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        storage.maxDownloadRetryTime = 10
        storage.maxOperationRetryTime = 10
        downloadImage()
    }

Comment: I tried this, but nothing changed :) Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Other solution?